# TeamCity AutoIncrementer Plugin Modify Build Number

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I'm using the TeamCity AutoIncrementer Plugin: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Autoincrementer

I'm attempting to modify the config file at: [TeamCity Data Directory]/config/autoincrementer.properties

Within the config file it says:

```
# Autoincrementer plugin (pre 6.5 EAP).
#
# This file contains values for auto-incremented properties.
# Each auto-incremented property must start with 'autoinc_Test.' prefix.
# Value of the property must be a positive integer.
# To use auto-incremented property in a build you can add a reference to the property
# in build configuration settings, e.g: %autoinc_Test.build.number%. When plugin discovers such reference
# initial value for the referenced property will be written in this file.
# You can change properties values in this file manually at any time.
# Note that if you want to set a property to some value you need to put ! character
# before the value (after the equals sign).
```

My values look like:

```
autoinc.foo=1683367\:25
autoinc.bar=-1\:10
```

I believe the first number is the changelist from Perforce.

I want to change the last number for foo from 25 to 200 (this is the build number).
I've tried putting the exclamation character at autoinc.foo=!1683367:200 and at autoinc.foo=1683367:!200. In both cases TeamCity will overwrite this file and change it back to 26 on the next build.

1) How do I change the build number? Does this require a TeamCity restart?

2) How is this working at all if each autoinc requires 'autoinc_Test.' prefix?

I am using TeamCity 8.0.6.

Answer (score 0):

The version we are using works by adding a !  after the = sign as per the comments in the file (e.g. autoinc.globalbuildnum=!1).
I noticed that the comments in the version we are using are different to those you have posted. We are using the plugin that is compatible with TeamCity 8.x+ which is currently at the link you posted. It was updated on 7th April 2015